Where can I find records of a French female citizen who immigrated to either Uruguay or Argentina bt 1903 and 1912?
I am doing my family genealogic research and I am trying to find records of the entry of one female French citizen, either through Montevideo or through Buenos Aires. There are records of her marriage in Uruguay in 1922, as well as other records of her living in Buenos Aires in 1919.
Where can I find the records of her port of entry and year of entry?

Comment rather than answer because I'm too lazy to distill it down to the relevant bits, but see this discussion on FS: https://community.familysearch.org/en/discussion/163742/are-there-immigration-and-naturalization-indexes-somewhere-for-argentina#latest, especially SantaNinfa's answer on June 28.

For Montevideo in FamilySearch, you have one collection you could check: Uruguay, Montevideo, Montevideo, registros migratorios, 1885-1980
For Buenos Aires, there are 5 collections: https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&placeId=1929509&query=%2Bplace%3A%22Argentina%2C%20Buenos%20Aires%22&subjectsOpen=712752-50
If you go to the Ancestry catalog, you can see what they have: https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/catalog?searchOrigin=navigation_header

As has been commented elsewhere, this "user" appears to be posting AI-generated content.
